# In windows cannot start schema registry from confluent

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I started zookeeper and kafka from the downloaded package here:
http://mirror.klaus-uwe.me/apache/kafka/2.4.0/kafka_2.13-2.4.0.tgz
Then I tried with this:
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry

1.in one command prompt I start zookeeper after changing the folder in \config\zookeeper.properties - line:

`dataDir=C:/KafkaConfl/zookeeper-data` (folder created by me)

2.changed also the config of the kafka server in the config\server.properties - line:

`-  log.dirs=c:\KafkaConfl\kafka-logs`

3. start zookeeper in one cmd prompt:

   > .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
4. wait and start kafka server in another cmd prompt:

   > .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
5. try with the schema registry:

   > .\bin\windows\schema-registry-start.bat C:\kafkaconfl\etc\schema-registry.properties

Error: Could not find or load main class io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain
Anybody with experience in Kafka / Windows can help, please?

Comment: Even i am facing the same issue. Please let me know if you fixed this issue